# Using ApplicationDBContext within a controller for ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I setup a few models for my application and added them up (with DbSet) to [ApplicationDBContext](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/identity/sample/src/ASPNETCore-IdentityDemoComplete/IdentityDemo/Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs) from the [Identity template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) but now I can't figure out how to access the context itself inside a controller.

Is there a global context I can use through dependency injection? Do I have to create a new context each time I make a request? If so, can I reuse the configuration from Startup.cs?

Adding an ApplicationDBContext parameter to my controller's constructor and then calling it from a function gives the following error :

> Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.`

```cs
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly UrlEncoder _urlEncoder;
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public MyController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        ILogger<ManageController> logger,
        UrlEncoder urlEncoder,
        MyContext context)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _urlEncoder = urlEncoder;
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async void Index()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async void AMethod(string parameter)
    {
        await _context.MyEntity.AddAsync(parameter);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code in Startup and your controller as well as your DbContext class?

Comment: Have you added ApplicationDbContext to DI /IoC container with `AddDbContext`?

Comment: The Startup.cs source is the same as [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/identity/sample/src/ASPNETCore-IdentityDemoComplete/IdentityDemo/Startup.cs). The base application itself works. I even tried adding another context following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)'s guidelines. I will edit my post to include the controller.

Comment: " Do I have to create a new context each time I make a request?" Generally, if you configured dependency injection correctly then it will be handled automatically, as`AddDbContext` adds it using `AddScoped` which is valid throughout the request.

Comment: Posting to http://localhost:5000/MyController/AMethod?parameter=foobar gives me a System.ObjectDisposedException

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://pgroene.wordpress.com/2017/12/22/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-in-asp-net-core-when-injecting-dbcontext/), it's because my function is `async void`. I changed it to `async Task` and now it works ._.